# How do I set the starting value of a time picker, only when it gets focus?

Tags: javascript, html, timepicker, html-input

I have a time picker:

`<input type="time" name="appt-time">`

I want to keep it empty until the user starts selecting a time. Only when the user clicks the element and the popup is shown do I want a default value to be shown.

Is that possible? if so how?

Comment: `<input type="time" value="13:30" name="appt-time">` ?

Comment: So you want to set the value for the popup but not the input itself? If so, why? What problem does it solve?

Comment: @Reyno Yes, Exactly that

Comment: @Ostone0. That sets the value initially instead of leaving it null

Comment: @Reyno The OP wants a default value on the popup but doesn't want it applied unless the user has actually selected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
  const time = "15:05";
  let changed = false;
  const timePicker = document.querySelector('[name="appt-time"]');
  timePicker.defaultValue = null;
  timePicker.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
    if (!changed) timePicker.value = time;
  });
  timePicker.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    changed = true;
  });
  timePicker.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    if (!changed) timePicker.value = null;
    else timePicker.defaultValue = timePicker.value; 
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="time" name="appt-time">
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, and then I can add an if statement in the focus event listener to set the starting point to the currently selected value if the input has a value already.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You mean set the `min(imum)` attribute or something?

Comment: As of now the script resets to the default value even if the user selected the input and thus choose a value, I added a  suggest-edit to fix the script

Comment: I just meant that after the value has been selected and they focus the element, I want to then display the selected time instead of the "time" value, not sure if that makes sense

Comment: @MervynLudick I made a small change to make it more sticky. There is one issue if the user wants to select the default value you have, then they need to set it to something else first

Comment: Didn't even think of that, wonder if there is a way around that.

Comment: I had "click" but that is not certain that they wanted that. What is the usecase for NOT wanting the time to be set or for the time to be cleared?